# Can I call a PL/SQL function created in Oracle Application Express into Jaspersoft Ireport?

Tags: plsql, jasper-reports, oracle-apex

Im creating reports using Jasper ireport. I created a PL/SQL function in Oracle Application Express to translate number in corresonding text .
eg. 125 to One Hunderd and Twenty Five.

Now i need to call this function into Jasper ireport by passing parameter imto this function. Is it possible?
I found ways to call procedure into ireport but I couldnt find ways to call a function into ireport. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your function is named `fnNumToStr`.

As we know from the basics, PL/SQL functions can be called from SQL queries if they accept and return values as SQL datatypes. In your example the function accepts number and returns `VARCHAR2` so it's fine.

Write a query like:

```
SELECT fnNumToStr(numCol)
  FROM tableName
```

Something like this should do. If you are passing parameter to this function then

```
SELECT fnNumToStr($P{paramName})
  FROM tableName
```

should do.

Comment: if I call the function it shows some parse error


http://i.stack.imgur.com/mUQ4K.jpg

Comment: There could be data type mismatch that you should check on. The data type of `$V{NET_AMOUNT_2}` must match the data type of input parameter for the function. Also, the `$V{NET_AMOUNT_2}` should not have any commas or other non-numeric values. If your function accepts only `INTEGER` numbers then `$V{NET_AMOUNT_2}` should also be an integer value.

Comment: $V.. stands for variable, but you should specify $P that should exist as created parameter